# How to combine JOINs in SQLite for my problem?

Tags: sqlite, join, combinations

I want to have a list with all my data from the table CITY and COUNTRY. But I am a beginner and I don't know all the statements.

**What I have are three tables, CITY, COUNTRY and LIST.**

For me is the the LIST-Table important because in my case that list has some filter information that I need later. For that example I removed all additional data. There are more "higher level" tables like CONTINET, etc. but for that example I want to make it simple.

```
CITY
CityID                               | CountryID                            |Name
cea36048-04b3-415f-bfbb-a19b44ef201c | 92a055dd-a61d-430c-99ca-0b77283cda62 | Linz
5ddb120b-34cf-4336-83a9-af8913c1447d | 92a055dd-a61d-430c-99ca-0b77283cda62 | Salzburg
20ba2ff4-980a-42d3-8386-a6bb097621ee | 92a055dd-a61d-430c-99ca-0b77283cda62 | Villach
9cd6c4bf-f03b-414f-a4c3-90081e3d8e3c | 295b7c40-b05b-499a-80cb-0f1c8bdf8a11 | Oakville
5efd9900-97b5-4f83-b467-918d23594d8f | 295b7c40-b05b-499a-80cb-0f1c8bdf8a11 | Thunder Bay
b35a43b8-39f1-4d77-ab6d-a48443b66bc1 | 71e57bd8-e546-4e54-9f30-7d913794954d | Danzig
01a512b8-a1a0-4e7a-95f5-6c7c587cd5c5 | 71e57bd8-e546-4e54-9f30-7d913794954d | Krakow
e22e4ded-19b6-47bc-9a01-0763b127a75f | 71e57bd8-e546-4e54-9f30-7d913794954d | Zakopane
5507d722-4a43-4f76-9738-b89aefdf7a11 | 295b7c40-b05b-499a-80cb-0f1c8bdf8a11 | Toronto
e69de000-2583-4ba1-8644-777ecbb51a69 | 295b7c40-b05b-499a-80cb-0f1c8bdf8a11 | Calgary

COUNTRY
CountryID                            | Name
92a055dd-a61d-430c-99ca-0b77283cda62 | Austria
295b7c40-b05b-499a-80cb-0f1c8bdf8a11 | Canada
71e57bd8-e546-4e54-9f30-7d913794954d | Poland
5a8b76d4-3ba2-4c0f-819f-54b47b9133b2 | India

LIST-TABLE
ID | AreaID
1  | 92a055dd-a61d-430c-99ca-0b77283cda62
2  | 295b7c40-b05b-499a-80cb-0f1c8bdf8a11
3  | 71e57bd8-e546-4e54-9f30-7d913794954d
4  | 5a8b76d4-3ba2-4c0f-819f-54b47b9133b2
5  | cea36048-04b3-415f-bfbb-a19b44ef201c
6  | 5ddb120b-34cf-4336-83a9-af8913c1447d
7  | 20ba2ff4-980a-42d3-8386-a6bb097621ee
8  | 9cd6c4bf-f03b-414f-a4c3-90081e3d8e3c
9  | 5efd9900-97b5-4f83-b467-918d23594d8f
10 | b35a43b8-39f1-4d77-ab6d-a48443b66bc1
11 | 01a512b8-a1a0-4e7a-95f5-6c7c587cd5c5
12 | e22e4ded-19b6-47bc-9a01-0763b127a75f
13 | 5507d722-4a43-4f76-9738-b89aefdf7a11
14 | e69de000-2583-4ba1-8644-777ecbb51a69
```

**What I want is:**

[image: list]

**Problem:**

I don't know how to create/combine the JOIN for the COUNTRY. I tried with LEFT OUTER, INNER etc. but all is not working.

```
SELECT CITY.CityID, CITY.Name, COUNTRY.CountryID, COUNTRY.Name FROM LIST
LEFT JOIN CITY ON LIST.AreaID = CITY.CityID
--LEFT JOIN COUNTRY ON LIST.AreaID = COUNTRY.CountryID
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY ON CITY.CountryID = COUNTRY.CountryID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The column `AreaID` of `LIST` may refer to either `CITY.CityID` or `COUNTRY.CountryID`, so you must join `LIST` to both `CITY` and `COUNTRY` and join also an extra copy of `COUNTRY` for the case that the match is found on a city and not a country:

```
SELECT t.CityID, t.Name, 
       COALESCE(c.CountryID, ct.CountryID) CountryID,
       COALESCE(c.Name, ct.Name) Name 
FROM LIST l
LEFT JOIN CITY t ON l.AreaID = t.CityID
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY c ON l.AreaID = c.CountryID
LEFT JOIN COUNTRY ct ON t.CountryID = ct.CountryID
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=2f96cf89ba6a18f5cf23ebad31210975).

Comment: Thanks!!! I tried already to join two tables but maybe I did something wrong